# LLBLGen Pro: How to evaluate an EntityField for a given String

Tags: vb.net, llblgenpro

I have an LLBLGen Pro project which has generated VB.Net 2.0 Self Servicing code.

I have a function to return a list of custom structures based on a search using the generated code.

I would like to supply a Dictionary of FieldNames and Values to this function and for each one add a new Predicate Expression to the search.

How can I check the String within the dictionary that represents the Field name and work out which EntityField to add the Predciate Expression for?

**Code Sample**

```
Dim dbFiles As New AllFilesCollection
Dim dbFilter As New PredicateExpression

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ClientName) Then
  dbFilter.Add(New PredicateExpression(AllFilesFields.ClientMenuName = ClientName))
End If

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText) Then
  dbFilter.Add(New FieldLikePredicate(AllFilesFields.ClientReference, "%" & SearchText & "%"))
  dbFilter.AddWithOr(New FieldLikePredicate(AllFilesFields.Cmsnumber, "%" & SearchText & "%"))
End If

For Each Filter As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Filters

  'Custom code here to determine the field to add a filter for.

Next

dbFiles.GetMulti(dbFilter)
```

Comment: Have you asked this on the support forums at LLBLGen - you're more likely to get an answer there...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this question has been ignored because it looks like an LLBLGEN question, but it probably isn't.

If you know all of your Columns:

- City
- State
- Zip

Then you just need to convert your string to those values like this...

```
For Each Filter As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Filters
    Select Case filter.Key
        Case "City"
            dbFilter.Add(New PredicateExpression(AllFilesFields.City = filter.Value))
        Case "State"
            dbFilter.Add(New PredicateExpression(AllFilesFields.State = filter.Value))
        Case "Zip"
            dbFilter.Add(New PredicateExpression(AllFilesFields.Zip = filter.Value))
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could do something like this:

```
Dim fields As IEntityFields = new AllFieldsEntityFactory().CreateFields();
For Each Filter As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Filters
    dbFilter.Add((EntityField) fields[Filter.Key] == Filter.Value);
Next
```